# CASE: WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN write column2

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to show data from another column if checked column IS NULL?

**For example**:

- **Columns**: `Color`, `OriginalColor`
- **Table**: `TableColors` `[Color, OriginalColor]`

  [W, B]
  [ , G]
  [B, Y]

And the

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Color IS NULL "extract the data from OriginalColor"
FROM TableColors
```

should get following list: W, G, B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you be looking for [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)? The function return the first non-`NULL` value.

```
SELECT COALESCE(`Color`, `OriginalColor`) AS `Color` FROM `TableColors`;
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks fine, and I tried it, but it reports this error: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '$SRG A' to data type int`.

Comment: @gaffcz - What are the data types for both fields? Are they the same? The query says that it's trying to convert an NVARCHAR into an INT. Are you trying to insert the data somewhere else? Obviously, you can't store a letter (i.e. A, B, G, ...) as an INT.

Comment: Its hard to say (for me), both of them are created over the several views, almost one of them is string

Comment: @gaffcz - It'll be hard to help you figure out what's wrong if you don't know what type of data you're dealing with. Like I explained above, it's trying to convert a `NVARCHAR` into an `INT`. Make sure that both `Color` and `OriginalColor` are both types that can store strings.

Comment: I'm trying something like `COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, color), CONVERT(NVARCHAR, originalColor)) AS col`, and It's little bit working, but for now, I've got the following error: `Cannot resolve collation conflict for DISTINCT operation` :)

Comment: @gaffcz: How did departments pop up out of the blue?

Comment: It's a magic.. I forgot to change it to colors, this is the real part of code :)

Comment: @Francois: This is the solution: `COALESCE(B.work_dept COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, D.Department) AS WorkDept`, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out coalesce - http://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/mysql-coalesce.shtml

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is quite clear about this:

- CASE statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-statement.html
- IF function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if
- IFNULL function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull
- COALESCE function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

The `IFNULL()` function might be the easiest solution to your problem

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN Color IS NULL THEN OriginalColor
ELSE Color
END  AS Color_Or_OriginalColor
FROM TableColors
```

Edit: *one* of the many possible ways.

Comment: Thank you, Salman! That was my first try, problem was in incompatible columns:)

Comment: @gaffcz: for different datatype columns you'll have to `CAST`/`CONVERT` one of the fields.

Comment: Jj, i've tried `COALESCE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, color), CONVERT(NVARCHAR, originalColor)) AS col` but it causes `Cannot resolve collation conflict for DISTINCT operation` so I had to use `COALESCE(color COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, originalColor) AS col`. And it works